# Tor + Privoxy on Debian Lenny Problems

Tags: debian, tor

I've followed the instructions here, to get it running on my debian server.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/debian-ubuntu-linux-install-onionrouter-software/

Everything is installed.

I've configured privoxy config and restarted both services after.

However, when I use 127.0.0.1:9050 as proxy, it says "TOR is not HTTP Proxy".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the web page you cite:

> Set 127.0.0.1 and 8118 as privoxy server IP and port number. Now Firefox is ready to use with Tor.

The http proxy is Privoxy, not Tor.